# Defining new functions using parameter text and using the signature

Tags: expl3, latex3, function

Have been reading the `expl3` document `interfaces3.pdf` to understand how to declare and use functions.  Although I have understood that there are three main methods (`new`, `set`, `gset`) where each method has specific use cases and restrictions upon parameter arguments.

Have also covered quite well the protected from expansion variants in certain contexts.

I would like some explanation about the difference between defining new functions using parameter text and defining new functions using the signature as covered in sections `4.3.2` and `4.3.3`.

Comment: you are presumably refering to `\cs_new:Nn` verses `\cs_new:Npn`  which is covered in `interface3.pdf` but you haven't given any example or mentioned expl3, so that's just a guess.

Comment: `set`/`gset` are not exactly different ways of defining from `new`. They're intended for redefining functions already declared with `new`. So you shouldn't do `set` or `gset` unless you did `new` or you're explicitly wanting to redefine a function declared with `new` elsewhere.

Comment: @cfr  That is ok.  The biggest wonder is parameter text versus signature.

Comment: It's not versus signature. All `expl3` functions have to have a signature. It's whether that signature is used to determine the expected parameters or whether the parameters are specified separately.

Comment: I don't know if my answer answers your question. The idea of parameters here is a TeX one. But I thought an example of why you might want the parametised form might help, since otherwise it might seem superfluous. Some people seem to use it as their default choice, whereas I'm lazy and let LaTeX figure it out from the signature when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code examples below are either from [Joseph Wright or derived from code from Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/) in answer to [my (much) earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327619/).

In standard cases, the difference is just one of how you prefer to specify the function. In the parametised case you specify the function's parameters explicitly:

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__chronos_set_minoryearformat:n #1
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__chronos_minoryearformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__chronos_minoryearformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
```

That is, the `#1` tells LateX the function takes a single argument, just as `\def\formatyear#1{ ... }` does.

In the non-parametised case, LaTeX infers the parameters from the new function's signature:

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__chronos_set_minoryearformat:n 
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__chronos_minoryearformat_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__chronos_minoryearformat_tl { ~ } { \c_space_token }
}
```

That is the `n` tells LaTeX the function takes a single argument, just as the `1` does in `\newcommand*\formatyear[1]{ ... }` or `m` does in `\NewDocumentCommand\formatyear{m}{ ... }`.

But in some cases, you want the parametised version because you want to handle the arguments passed to the function specially.

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__chronos_set_date_aux_ce:w #1 - #2 - #3 - #4 @#5 \q_stop
{
    \__chronos_set_date:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#5}
}
```

So this function doesn't expect some mixture of tokens and braced lists of tokens. It expects something with a non-standard syntactical form.

This makes it possible to parse user input of dates which differ in how much information they provide. Basically, the user can say

```
date={1066-08-09}
```

or

```
date=1066
```

or

```
date={1066-03}
```

The package then adds to the user-specified input

```
<user-specified date>-01-01-0@start \q_stop
```

and the code will pass the appropriate information on. If the user only specified a year, a month and day will be added. If the user specified only a year and month, a day will be added. If the user specified a full date, nothing will be added except `start` which is used to create variable names.

This is why `w`. `w` is for 'weird'.

This is basically like similar definitions at the TeX level.

```
\def\mydateparser@aux#1-#2-#3-#4@#5\@nil{ ... }
```

would work similarly (except this isn't protected and there is no check to ensure the definition isn't obliterating some crucial thing).

Comment: Right, I have only had experience with non-parametised version, where I do not specify `#1` at the end.

Comment: How would you describe the non-parametised and parametised versions briefly.  Haw would you describe them ?

Comment: This does not say much in terms of understanding `p and w   These are special cases.`

Comment: @Fluffy See edit.

Comment: @Fluffy the `p` argument is a special case and means parameter text.

Comment: @cfr, May I ask where you got the example code from? I do not see a package called "chronos" on CTAN. (although chronosys is available) Also I do not see anything about "chronos" on Joseph Wright's github page.

Comment: @User23456234 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327619/ is the question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327642/ is Joseph's answer, referenced above. I've edited the links into the answer.